# SelectionChanged called each time ItemsSource is define

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, selectionchanged

i look for this problem in forums but i don't get an understandable answer.
I have a listView (lstInterrogateur), each time i click on an item, i load data in another listview.
It works fine!
I have a combbox above (cboMatiere), which filter data of the listview lstInterrogateur. When i select item in the combobox, the listview load filtered data. So i make my query and:

```
lstInterrogateur.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

But this line call:

```
lstInterrogateur_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

in this section of code, i get the selected index, but, no index is select ans an error is generated.

How can i prevent the execution of this event?

Thanks.

Comment: Solution: Create the `CollectionView` only once, and leave the UI untouched. Also, instead of `selectionchanged` type of stuff, use `SelectedItem="{Binding Something}"` and handle that at the ViewModel level.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i solved my problem simply, i just added these 2 lines at the beginning of the procedure:

```
if (lstInterrogateur.SelectedItem == null)
                return;
```